# Redux not work inside in NEXT JS middleware

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How to use Redux inside NEXTJS middleware?
Any suggestion to achieve this problem, I try my useSelector in my index it's works fine but in middleware I don't know how to use it I'm newbie in nextjs.

```
//middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { store} from './store/store';

export  function  middleware(request) {
  const auth = store.getState().user;
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
    if(auth ){
       return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/' , request.url))
    }
  }
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
    // This logic is only applied to /dashboard
  }
}
```

Comment: Using Redux on the server is used to set the initial state, you won't be able to access state that was previously set on the client-side. You should retrieve the user's auth state by other means, e.g. using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like reducers are not meant to be changed server side. I read a very similar issue here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1745 Give it a try. Hope its helpful.

Comment: not work also createStore in deprecated

Comment: Here there's an official example from the Next's github Examples repository where it shows how to work with middlewares. Give it a try. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux

Comment: I used store.getState().user for Server Rendering https://redux.js.org/usage/server-rendering but it returned to null value even I dispatched already